# Pointer arithmetic for structures gives strange result

Tags: c, pointers

I have following function:

```
void deleteInventory( struct book** inventory )
{
    struct book* ptr = NULL;
    ptr = *inventory;

    while( length != 0)
    {
        free(ptr);
        length--;
        ++ptr;
    }
    free(inventory);
}
```

Structure:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 64
#define ISBN_LENGTH 11

struct book
{
    char isbn[ISBN_LENGTH];
    char title[MAX_LENGTH];
    char author[MAX_LENGTH];
    int year;
    float price;
};
```

Total size of the structure: **147 bytes** (11 + 64 + 64 + 4 + 4)
sizeof(struct book) returns: **148 bytes**

My inventory variable is array of structures and contains 3 records

Now, results of debugging in the function (addresses without high 2 bytes):

```
inventory[0] = 0x1350
inventory[1] = 0x14e0
inventory[2] = 0x1670
```

Difference in memory: 400 bytes, OK

On first iteration everything is OK, first record deletes without a problems

But after

```
++ptr;
```

ptr will contain: **0x13e4**

**inventory[0] - ptr = 148 bytes** - correct difference according to structure's size

but it does not refers to next record, because address of the next record in memory:  **0x14e0** and I'm getting corruption of the heap.

Any suggestions: why?

Comment: In `deleteInventory` the `length` variable is uninitialized when you use it.

Comment: You may have done pointer arithmetic on the second pointer that is off. -- suggestion only.  There are tools like special malloc libraries and valgrind to pinpoint you issue.  Edit: @mbratch looks to have a solution, unless length is a global variable. +1

Comment: @mbratch `length` is global variable :)

Comment: why don't you use an std::vector<book> and std::string instead of the char arrays?

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: How is the original array initialized?

Comment: @denis90 OK, but make sure it's properly initialized. Global doesn't guarantee that. :)

Comment: @PlasmaHH This is C, not C++

Comment: Are you sure inventory is an array of structures, and not an array to pointers of structures?

Comment: @denis90: Why is it then tagged as C++?

Comment: Need to see how you're calling `deleteInventory`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are deleting incorrectly from the `inventory`. After you `free(ptr)` then next memory block after `ptr` will probably be junk memory. Here i think is the correct way of deleting your inventory:

```
void deleteInventory( struct book** inventory )
{
    book** i =  inventory;
    while( length != 0)
    {
        free(*i);
        length--;
        ++i;//notice the difference (++i) instead of (++(*i))
    }
    free(inventory);
}
```

Comment: `++i` will increment the pointer-to-pointer.  Not the desired behaviour.

Comment: And it works, because it's not an array of structs, but an array of pointers to structs.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth am i missing someting ? `free(ptr)` then `ptr++` , `free(ptr)` again , this is UB

Comment: @Raxvan: But in the OP's code, `ptr` is initialized to `*inventory` (note the `*`).  It's clear that the OP didn't describe his memory layout sufficiently...

Answer (score 7):

You've said that `inventory` is an array, and that's fine.

You've said that `book` takes up 148 bytes (when you count padding), and that's fine.

What you haven't said is that the pointers you place in `inventory` are allocated all at once, and the fact that you have an array of pointers implies to me that they're not.

However you create each of the `book`s, it seems to be dynamically.  There's no guarantee that the books will be contiguous, only that the pointers to them will be.

Change your function:

```
void deleteInventory( struct book** inventory )
{
    struct book* ptr = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        ptr = inventory[i];
        free(ptr);
    }
    length = 0;
    free(inventory);
}
```

This will read the contiguous pointer-to-`book` array to delete all the `book`s, without assuming that the `book`s themselves are contiguously allocated.

Comment: This is the simplest solution and not interested!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, the main goal is use of pointer arithmetic, not indexing

Answer (score 2):

We can only speculate how `inventory` and its contents came to live, but since you free them individually, you probably have `malloc()`d them individually too. But you go through them via `ptr` and `ptr++` which assumes contiguous allocated structure members, just like you would have in an array.

However nothing guarantees (and the average implementation will also not do it) that `malloc()` will return in any way contiguous storage for consecutive allocations.

This is why you see them more than the 148 bytes apart that you expect. Since probably inventory is an array to the allocated pointers, what you want to do is:

```
while( length != 0)
{
    free(*inventory);
    length--;
    ++inventory;
}
```

Comment: And how will I free memory at the end for `inventory`?

Comment: @denis90: That stays the way it is, I only mentioned the key part, didn't rewrite the whole program.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer arithmetic is not the issue... the problem is your assumptions on how the arrays are laid out is wrong.

I'm guessing you did something like:

```
  length = 3;
  inventory = (struct book**) malloc(sizeof(struct book *) * length);
  ...
  inventory[0] = (struct book*) malloc(sizeoof(struct book));
  inventory[1] = ... etc ;
```

Then you assign ptr to inventory[0];

```
  ptr = *inventory;
```

But then you assume that

```
 ++ptr == inventory[1];
```

and that is not true.